# Intellij Idea 2017 not reading idea64.vmoptions

Tags: intellij-idea

Using Ubuntu, i have both intellij 2016 and intellij 2017. I configure idea64.vmoptions for both in the respective folder: `~/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/` and `/.IntelliJIdea2017.2`. for both i upgraded the memory size. while 2016 version reads this value (as i see in the memory indicator), 2017 versions doesn't. I tried everything.

this is idea64.vmoptions:

```
-Xms2128m
-Xmx2750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than attempting to find the correct file on the file system you can do this from within the IDE from the menu item:

`Help > Edit Custom VM Options`

This will present the `vmoptions` file which is actually in use allowing your to edit it within the IDE. Once you have completed your edit, just restart IntelliJ and you'll see the changes take effect.

More details in [the docs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties).

Answer (score 0):

1、You can set it from here:
[image: You can set it from here]

2、Open the edit page:
[image: Open the edit page]

3、Then restart, it will take effect:
[image: Then restart, it will take effect]

Comment: As links maight change over time, please add relevan sections of the answer here itself.

Comment: thanks,but now i'm not allowed to embed images in my posts yet,When I have the right, I will come back and modify it.@HarshWardhan